# Display object content with IE9 debug mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firebug

I have some JS which works with FF but not IE.  While I like firebug more, IE9's debug mode (F12) isn't bad.  Problem is I can't figure out how to display the content of an object like console.log(obj) does with firebug.  Can anyone help?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [console.dir()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to display the object

```
console.dir(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks epascarello.  Looks like both console.dir and console.log should work.  Problem is both for some reason are not displaying the content on the console screen.  Strange...

Comment: Well, I feel stupid.  They were being displayed all along, but the window was scrolled up too high and I couldn't see them on the screen.

Comment: console.dir() isn't ideal, but maybe is the best there is.  It lists methods as well as properties, and I really only wanted properties.  Furthermore, it doesn't give the content of the object, but just calls them something like "object HTMLInputElement".

Comment: Only other solution you have is to loop through the object yourself and basically recreate the functionality that the other debuggers have.

Answer (score 0):

You can set breakpoints and use the watch feature to look at objects, but I'm not sure it will give you the same level of detail exposed in Firebug

Have you tried [Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)?

Comment: Thanks danwellman.  Yes, tried firebug lite and it was okay. Since IE9, however, I think the built in stuff is better.